# Android: add button and rectangle to layout

Tags: android, button, attributes, 2d

I'm new to Android. Here I draw a rectangle.

```
public class DrawView extends View  
{
     Paint paint = new Paint();

     public DrawView(Context context) 
     {
          super(context);            
     }

     @Override
     public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)     
     {
          paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
          canvas.drawRect(30f, 30f, 80f, 80f, paint);
     }
}
```

My XML code for adding button is :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have 2 doubts.

1)I want the rectangle in top of the app and the button in the bottom. How should I do it?

2) Later I want to change the color of rectangle. How should I get the rectangle to change the attributes?

Comment: `android:layout_alignParentTop"true"`for the rectangle and http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html for the colour attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Add the rectangle to your layout xml.-

```
<packageRouteToYourExtendedView.DrawView
     android:id="@+id/rectangle"
     android:layout_width="30dp"
     android:layout_height="80dp"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

**2)** Add a method to your extended view to change the color.-

```
public class DrawView extends View  
{
     Color color = Color.BLACK;
     Paint paint = new Paint();

     public DrawView(Context context) 
     {
          super(context);            
     }

     @Override
     public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)     
     {
          paint.setColor(color);
          canvas.drawRect(30f, 30f, 80f, 80f, paint);
     }

     public changeColor(Color color) {
         this.color = color;
         invalidate();
     }
}
```

And get the rectangle view to call your new method.-

```
DrawView rectangle = findViewById(R.id.rectangle);
rectangle.changeColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Comment: Thanks ssantos. But if I want to have 100 rectangles like a grid. I will draw all in a 2 for loop in a draw function. Now how should I access each rectangle?

Comment: So you'll have 1 view that will draw all rectangles? Then you can keep an array of colors (or array of arrays), to keep the color of each rectangle given its row/column position, and have a method `changeColor(Color color, int row, int col);`